# Nubia Z9 gives error on starting camera

Tags: camera

I bought the nubia z9 mini last year November.

About a week ago this message appears when using the camera:

"camera error" 
"Please make sure no other applications occupy the camera, or try to restart the phone. "

I tried restarting but the same error. As requested, I've run `adb dumpsys`:

```
> adb shell dumpsys media.camera
Camera module HAL API version: 0x100
Camera module API version: 0x100
Camera module name: QCamera Module
Camera module author: Qualcomm Innovation Center Inc
Number of camera devices: 2 Vendor tags left unimplemented.
Camera 0 static information:
   Facing: BACK Orientation: 90
   Device version: 0x100
   Device is closed, no client instance
Camera 1 static information:
   Facing: FRONT
   Device version: 0x100
```

I put the New version V3.67 Android Version 5.1.1 [ROM], the error is same.
Can you help me?

Comment: 1. the ADB setup and command ready in PC 
2. device connected to PC in debugging mode. 
3. run the camera app.
Disappeared the error, the camera turns on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem (thanks to [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord)):

While "being debugged", the camera is turned on. For that, I've simply did the following:

1. the ADB setup and command ready in PC
2. device connected to PC in debugging mode.
3. run `adb logcat > d:\dmp\device.log`
4. run the camera app. Disappeared the error, the camera turns on